# Use Data From One SQL Table and Correlate It To Data In Another Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

First off, I'm doing this for purely educational purposes. I have a Kodi (XBMC) plugin that goes through my TV Show database and stores which episodes have been watched and how many times. I figured out how to use HTML forms to retrieve data (TheTVDB ID number, Season, Episode numbers, and how many times the episode has been played) from my database using PHP. In an attempt to further my knowledge, I'm trying to convert the "friendly" show name which is taken by the form, then convert it to the ID number, and use that stored value in another query on a different table in the same database to return the Episode and Season Numbers.

For example, *Friends* is `ID# 79168`. The table **tvshows** contains columns  `idShow` and `titles`, whereas the table **episode_watched** contains columns `idShow`, `season`, `episode` and `playCount`. After `idShow` is correlated to `title`, I would like to output a table with the columns **Season** and **Episode** which match the specific playcount and title.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/i7Y2ZWpR

This is the PHP error that I'm getting:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/share/webapps/pydio/sql.php on line 15

0 Results

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a resource in the second query rather then a result
2. You are not enclosing your strings in the query in semi colons
3. Your code is SQL Injectable.

Lets fix that:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <?php
      $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "WatchedList");
      $showname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["showname"]); //Prevents SQLi
       $title = $mysqli->query("SELECT idShow FROM tvshows WHERE title='$showname'"); //Added ' and '
       $res = $title->fetch_assoc(); //fetch the result to grab idshow 
       $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT season,episode FROM episode_watched WHERE idShow='" . $res['idShow'] . "' and playCount>=3"); //added ' and '
        //Outputs the data in a table
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<table><tr><th>Season</th><th>Episode</th></tr>";
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["season"]."</td><td>".$row["episode"]."</td></tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
        }
        else {
          echo "0 Results";
        }
        $mysqli->close();
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help.